# F.G. abelian group so that every quotient is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated

I need to characterize every finitely generated abelian group G that has the following property:
$$\frac{G}{S} \text{ is cyclic for every } S\leq G$$
I know I am supposed to use the structure theorem to reach contradictions about the underlying structure of the decomposition (for example only one or two primes in its decomposition and such). However, I can't seem to figure out precisely how to reach such contradictions with this property.

Comment: Setting $S=\{e\}$ will tell you a lot ...

Comment: Yes, I should have added that S must be non-nil. Editing it now.

Comment: Clearly, $G/G$ is cyclic (in fact, it is the trivial group), so it doesn't matter whether the improper subgroup is excluded or not. What matters is that the trivial subgroup (not the improper one) is excluded.

Comment: Please don't change questions after they have been correctly answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @Troposphere's hint, we get that $G $ is cyclic.  (So it's singly generated.)